# How to Perform delete and Edit in sql from grid view in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, ado.net, c#-3.0

How to perform delete and update records in SQL table from grid view in c#.
I had tried it in many ways but it is not working out in any of the way.
Please help me to solve this problem to add delete and edit functionality to my grid view to edit my sql table.

```
 protected void userlist_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
            userlist.DeleteRow(e.RowIndex);

    }
    protected void userlist_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        userlist.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        DataBind();
    }

    protected void userlist_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        try
        {
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PMS"].ToString();

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

           // SqlCommand cmd = "UPDATE  UserDT SET (UserId,UserName, Password, Email, PhoneNumber )" + "VALUES ('"+ UserName.Text +"' + tbxPassword.Text + tbxPermission.Text + "');";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           Note.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this will help [Asp.net insert, Edit, update, delete data in gridview](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html).

Comment: thanks but is did not work properly.

Comment: It should work you might miss something important, Can you update your question here with the code you've tried and error details if any?

Comment: i tried the code you have sent me before you refer me and tried again as you have sent me but getting the same error index out of range Exception

Comment: you can try  `userlist.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex - 1` in an `userlist_RowEditing()` event.

Comment: can you please send me the complete syntax for that @RahulHendawe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use as shown below. 
For Insert from the gridview Design columns tag

```
<Columns>   
    <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAddNew" Text="Add New" runat="server" CommandName="AddNew" ToolTip="ADD"/>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns> 

protected void EmpGrid_Command(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
    {
        TextBox txtf = (TextBox)EmpGrid.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFooterFname");
        TextBox txtl = (TextBox)EmpGrid.FooterRow.FindControl("txtfooterLname");
        TextBox txtq = 
                (TextBox)EmpGrid.FooterRow.FindControl("txtfooterqualification");
        TextBox txtd = 
                (TextBox)EmpGrid.FooterRow.FindControl("txtfooterdecription");
        TextBox txts = (TextBox)EmpGrid.FooterRow.FindControl("txtfootersalary");

        // For Inserting New Row
        string insrtquery = "insert into EMPTable
                            (fname,lname,qualification,designation,sal) values
                            ('" + txtf.Text + "','" + txtl.Text + "',
                             '" + txtq.Text + "','" + txtd.Text + "','" +
                                  txts.Text + "')";
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(insrtquery, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds,"inserted");
        Bindemployees();
     }       
}

protected void EmpGrid_Updating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
int empid = Convert.ToInt32(EmpGrid.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
string fname = EmpGrid.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["fname"].ToString();
string lname = EmpGrid.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["lname"].ToString();
TextBox txtq = 
       (TextBox)EmpGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditqualification");
TextBox txtd = 
       (TextBox)EmpGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditdesignation");
TextBox txts = 
       (TextBox)EmpGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditsalary");

string updatequery = "update EMPTable set qualification='" + txtq.Text +
                   "',designation='" + txtd.Text + "',sal='" + txts.Text + "'
                   where empid='" + empid + "'";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da = new SqlDataAdapter(updatequery,con);
da.Fill(ds,"added");
EmpGrid.EditIndex = -1;
Bindemployees();
}

protected void EmpGrid_Deleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
int empid = Convert.ToInt32(EmpGrid.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
da = new 
SqlDataAdapter("delete from EMPTable where empid='" + empid + "'", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds,"deleted");
Bindemployees();
}
```

For better understanding see this link

http://reddyinfosoft.blogspot.in/2012/07/insert-edit-update-and-delete-with-in.html

Comment: Sorry to say but i am getting the index out of range Exception to use this code, I had already tried using similar code for at that time also i was getting index out of range exception.

Comment: Solved the Index Out of range Exception now....
i am unable to take input to textbox from grid for updating the DB with new record I am getting NULL in textbox

Comment: @ROHITMANDALAPU hi, did you used `e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew")` in `EmpGrid_Command` as shown in the above link?

Comment: i had not tried any such can you help me with syntax.

Comment: @ROHITMANDALAPU updated the comment let me know. else download the application from the blog post and check.

Comment: can you please send me the link of the blog post. or can you please update that in the code posted.

Comment: @ROHITMANDALAPU At the end of the post there is a link to download. Just download from there.

Answer (score 0):

you're binding to a DataTable. Try this:

```
DataTable sourceData = (DataTable)userlist.DataSource;
sourceData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Delete();
userlist.DataSource = sourceData;
userlist.DataBind();
```

Comment: sorry to say but getting following error.

An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in DB Prac.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataSet' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.